# add dynamic values in liveagent.addCustomDetail('name',name)..?

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console

I want pass some custom details filled on html page to pre chat form by live agent
addCustomDetails method. This should be written before iveagent.init method otherwise it gives error:
Uncaught Error: You cannot add a detail after page initialization.

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: What details do you want to pass? From where are you taking those details? Are you using a controller on the pre-chat form? There are different ways of doing this so it would be better if you share the code you have created.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la3-c2cs-chi.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/33.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
liveagent.addCustomDetail('email','pankaj8261@gmail.com');
liveagent.addCustomDetail('name', 'pankaj');
liveagent.init('https://d.la3-c2cs-chi.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5721900000029', '00D19000000FF1xA'); 
</script>                                    Now I want to add those details in javascript method on clickof button .

Comment: It's an old question, but I would still like an answer if anybody knows. Our use-case is to send what page the user is on while using single-page app. It could also be something that would change based on what user have done while on the given page and then click on Live Agent chat icon